# How to fix Server Error, connect ETIMEDOUT after execute 'firebase deploy'

Tags: firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm recently working with Firebase. After practice with some services, Iwanted to deploy my functions. However, every time I want to deploy it, a timeout error appears.

I'm working with Ubuntu 19.04 and the version of firebase cli is 7.3.0

This is the error, sometimes the timeout appears before and any line.

```
firebase deploy --only functions:helloWorld --debug
[2019-09-01T14:47:30.465Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-09-01T14:47:30.470Z] Command:       /opt/nodejs/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64/bin/node /opt/nodejs/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64/bin/firebase deploy --only functions:helloWorld --debug
[2019-09-01T14:47:30.471Z] CLI Version:   7.3.0
[2019-09-01T14:47:30.471Z] Platform:      linux
[2019-09-01T14:47:30.471Z] Node Version:  v10.16.0
[2019-09-01T14:47:30.472Z] Time:          Sun Sep 01 2019 09:47:30 GMT-0500 (GMT-05:00)
[2019-09-01T14:47:30.472Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-09-01T14:47:30.483Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2019-09-01T14:47:30.483Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[2019-09-01T14:47:30.484Z] [iam] checking project angular-preview-5ac98 for permissions ["cloudfunctions.functions.create","cloudfunctions.functions.delete","cloudfunctions.functions.get","cloudfunctions.functions.list","cloudfunctions.functions.update","cloudfunctions.operations.get","firebase.projects.get"]
[2019-09-01T14:47:30.486Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/angular-preview-5ac98:testIamPermissions  
 permissions=[cloudfunctions.functions.create, cloudfunctions.functions.delete, cloudfunctions.functions.get, cloudfunctions.functions.list, cloudfunctions.functions.update, cloudfunctions.operations.get, firebase.projects.get]
[2019-09-01T14:47:31.973Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, date=Sun, 01 Sep 2019 14:47:31 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=0, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, server-timing=gfet4t7; dur=124, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39", accept-ranges=none, transfer-encoding=chunked
=== Deploying to 'angular-preview-5ac98'...
i  deploying functions
[2019-09-01T14:47:33.372Z] > [functions] package.json contents: {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
[2019-09-01T14:47:33.373Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/angular-preview-5ac98/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com  
[2019-09-01T14:47:33.374Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/angular-preview-5ac98/services/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com  
[2019-09-01T14:47:33.956Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, date=Sun, 01 Sep 2019 14:47:33 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=0, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39", accept-ranges=none, transfer-encoding=chunked
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
[2019-09-01T14:49:43.050Z] Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.217.8.106:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
Error: Server Error. connect ETIMEDOUT 172.217.8.106:443
```

I use the services of hosting. I deployed an app with integration with firestore without any error. I want to know the reason of this problem.

Comment: If you're having problems deploying with the Firebase CLI, please contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I executed all the commands to deploy my functions in other machine and in other network. It's possibly that my internet is unstable.

At this moment, I'm using the integration of Github with Travis CI to deploy my functions and I have no problems by the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the Network router worked for me.